# How to make image wheelview (horizontal and vertical)

Tags: android, image-gallery

i m making image slider like this in android but not able to find similar like this lib.

[image]

i found this 2 lib, but both are in IOS, is it possible to make slider like this, any suggestion would be helpful. Thank YOu.

http://www.code4app.com/thread-6046-1-1.html

http://www.code4app.com/thread-11971-1-1.html

here this is my final goal to make a slider like this

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a look into these libraries.

- [AndroidSwipeableCardStack](https://github.com/wenchaojiang/AndroidSwipeableCardStack)
- [CardStackView](https://github.com/loopeer/CardStackView)
- [Card Stack View](https://github.com/yuyakaido/CardStackView)
- [android-swipecards-view](https://github.com/Arjun-sna/android-swipecards-view)
- [Swipe-Deck](https://github.com/aaronbond/Swipe-Deck)
- [PlaceHolderView](https://github.com/janishar/PlaceHolderView)
- [android-swipecards-view](https://github.com/Arjun-sna/android-swipecards-view)

However you would have to tweak with the options so as to get the exact look of the design.

Comment: perfect bro.. Thank you so much

Comment: Glad to help! Cheers!